# Cannot get the red rectangles around required input elements when validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

To start with, below are my two model classes.

```
public class DataModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string                  SubscriptionName    { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public SubscriptionDateModel SubscriptionExpiry { get; set; }

        public DataModel()
        {
            SubscriptionExpiry = new SubscriptionDateModel();
        }
    }

    public class SubscriptionDateModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
        {
            get
            {
                var Months = new List<SelectListItem>();
                Months.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "-----", Value = "0" });
                string[] MonthList = new string[12] { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" };
                int MonthIndex = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < MonthList.Length; i++)
                {
                    MonthIndex = i + 1;
                    var item = new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Selected = (Month == MonthIndex),
                        Text = MonthList[i],
                        Value = MonthIndex.ToString()
                    };
                    Months.Add(item);
                }
                return Months;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
        {
            get
            {
                var Years = new List<SelectListItem>();
                Years.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "-----", Value = "0" });
                string[] YearList = new string[9] { "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020" };
                int YearIndex = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < YearList.Length; i++)
                {
                    YearIndex = i + 1;
                    var item = new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Selected = (Month == YearIndex),
                        Text = YearList[i],
                        Value = YearIndex.ToString()
                    };
                    Years.Add(item);
                }
                return Years;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have an editor template called SubscriptionDate.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.SubscriptionDateModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, Model.Years, new { id = "Year"})&nbsp;@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month, Model.Months, new { id = "Month"})&nbsp;
```

> I am using this template in the Index.cshtml as follows

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.DataModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Required field")
    <br />
     @Html.Label("Subscription Name: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubscriptionName)
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Subscription Expiry: ")
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubscriptionExpiry, "SubscriptionDate")

    <input type="submit" value="Check" />
}
```

and finally in controller my action methods are defined as follows.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View(new DataModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(DataModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Hello world";
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

My problem is that if user hits the Check button without entering any information, I need to get that Red rectangle around the two input elements but its not happening. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to put Site.css and jQuery library in the page as well.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Update:**

> I need to get that Red rectangel around the two input elements but its
>   not happening.

You can fix in CSS. Visual Studio default template come with below Site.css (both Intranet/Internet). Invalid validation "red" border for textbox is over written by "`border: 1px solid #ccc`". So just comment out this line and it should be fine.

```
/* FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS 
.....
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but still didn't get those rectanlges :(

Comment: Check your default css for "input" which is under "FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS" section.

Comment: Thanks Min, That definitely solves the problem for the text box, however my template still not getting that red rectangle. When I inspect it using firebug, I don't see any input-validation-error class attached to individual drop-downs. Anything I may be missing when creating this custom template?

Comment: Is it your "Year" and "Month" drop-downs in the template validating? Suspect that validation will always pass because of your default value for "----" would be 0. Try to set "" for default selectlistitem value.

Comment: -1 It's better to override the css for the extra class than to edit the css by removing fields in order to allow the other css show up.  See @AaronLS's answer for an example of this.

Answer (score 3):

Add `!important` to the input-validation-error class.  The `input[type="text"]` in Site.css has higher specificity and thus trumps the validation border.

```
.input-validation-error { 
   border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important; 
   background-color: #ffeeee; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you linking the generated `site.css`? In there, there are some css classes, like `input-validation-error`, which provides the red borders.

Check with a tool like firebug if the invalidated input field got the class `input-validation-error`. If it did, it is a css mismatch and you probably didn't link to the `Site.css` or removed the `input-validation-error` class. In those cases, defining the css class in your css should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can see that input field has go the class and site.css has input-validation-error class defined as well. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Then it is definitely a css mismatch. Causes are, like I said, a css file which isn't linked, but it is also possible that you have overwritten the border somewhere by overwriting the class or using `border: (...) !important;`

Comment: I used a new MVC 3 (intranet) project template in visual studio. At this point, my code is exactly what I posted in this question. All other code is whatever is packaged in the VS template.